# How to deal with blank spaces in names

Tags: r

I have the following string:

```
str(data)
# List of 3
#  $ posterior                                         :Class 'xxx'  atomic 
#  $ num_diversity_Categories                          :Class 'xxx'  atomic 
#  $ num of species                                    :Class 'xxx'  atomic
```

I can use `data$posterior` to get the data for the first string. But for the third name, the one having blank spaces, how can I call it?

Comment: `data$\`num of species\`` or make new and correct names with `make.names(names(data))`

Comment: Also `data[["num of species"]]`